# urlauthorization with custom roleprovider

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, global-asax, roleprovider

I am interacting with a third party httpmodule for authentication. I implemented my custom roleprovider to interact with that. However they use a CustomPrincipal instead of the expected RolePrincipal for urlauthorization.

In which event in global.asax can I hook to grab the customprincipal, instantiate a new RolePrincipal and copy over the custom Identity implementation they provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use Application_AuthenticateRequest event

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. At the moment I believe it is in the PostAuthenticaterequest where they set the principal. I guess I need to ask them to change this event to AuthenticateRequest then.